# Problem with ObservableCollection in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

I have written code below, my problem is that in the view it shows only the first value which is added in the loop, but I have more values there. I don't know where I made a mistake. If anyone has some ideas let me know.

```
 public class NumbersViewModel : IAsyncInitialization, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private ObservableCollection<ContactsListModel> _exampleList = new ObservableCollection<ContactsListModel>();
    public Task Initialization { get; private set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<ContactsListModel> ExampleList 
    {   get => _exampleList;
        set
        {               
            _exampleList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Number");
        }
    }

    public NumbersViewModel()
    {
        Initialization = InitializeAsync();
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {

        var items = new ObservableCollection<ContactsListModel>(); // new collection
        var contacts = await Plugin.ContactService.CrossContactService.Current.GetContactListAsync();
        var listOfPhones = App.UserPreferences.GetPhoneNumber(contacts);

        foreach (var item in listOfPhones)
            ExampleList.Add(new ContactsListModel() { Number = item });

    }
}

public interface IAsyncInitialization
{
    Task Initialization { get; }
}
```

This is my view, I think I made everything good.

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,0,20,0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ExampleList}"  Grid.Row="1">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding Number}"></TextCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Did you debug on `var listOfPhones = App.UserPreferences.GetPhoneNumber(contacts);` to see if it is single item ? If possible could you provide a basic sample for testing  ?

Comment: listOfPhones work without any problems it takes proper amount of numbers from user phone

Comment: Your binding hasn’t been done properly. Could you please share the page c# file code as well? Have you taken a look at this: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/151067/xamarin-forms-list-view-doesnt-display-added-items-instantly-with-observable-collection

Comment: are you sure, your list shows only one item? Row Height 50 isn't very height, maybe you SEE only one row, but when you scroll, then you can see the others. For tests, set Row Height = " * " for Row 1